# How to get Ajax links marked as "visited" without messing up IE9

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, internet-explorer

I have a page full of links that each AJAX in an article based off an ID. I'm trying to use history.pushstate to mark articles as "visited".

What I've done:

I added a hash to each link with the ID of the article:

```
<a href="#ID=123" onclick="ajaxLoad('123')">Title</a>
```

Inside my JS function I have something like:

```
if (window.history && window.history.pushState)
{
    window.history.pushState({articleID:"123"}, "Title",  "#ID=123");
}
```

The value inside my href is not used in anyway, I just put it there so that the links would get "visited" CSS. This works well in most browser except of course IE9. Since IE9 does not support window.history, I never expected it to work.

However, my problem is that clicking articles in IE changes the URL to append the hashes on them and this pollutes the history (now have to click back a whole bunch of times to go back).

I know that I could get rid of the hashes and still have back button work (outside of IE), but I'm actually more interested in making sure my links get marked as "visited". Is there anyway to get ajaxy links marked as "visited" without having IE9 behavior compromised?

Comment: Use a library that adds history support that does not support pushState.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this to your `onclick` handler:

```
if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault(); else event.returnValue = false;
```

Comment: Thanks Neil! I did not know about event.returnValue, but that did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Simply `return false;` from your `onclick` handler.

Comment: doesn't work, IE still updates the URL with the hash and it still cycles through it when using back button